# How do i send the values of a dynamic form from react to node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios, dynamicform

I'm trying to design a dynamic form where if user needs to insert more than one resource person details they can click on the + sign and the same textboxes will be displayed again. The values from the dynamic form should be stored in the database at the same time.
The image displayed below is my dynamic form

[image: The image displayed below is my dynamic form]

Event.js (React)

```
function Event() {
 
  const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([
    {
      ResourcePersonName: "",
      ResourcePersonDesignation: "",
      ResourcePersonContact: "",
      ResourcePersonEmail: "",
    },
  ]);

  const handleInputChange = (index, event) => {
    const values = [...inputFields];
    if (event.target.name === "ResourcePersonName") {
      values[index].ResourcePersonName = event.target.value;
    } else if (event.target.name === "ResourcePersonDesignation") {
      values[index].ResourcePersonDesignation = event.target.value;
    } else if (event.target.name === "ResourcePersonContact") {
      values[index].ResourcePersonContact = event.target.value;
    } else {
      values[index].ResourcePersonEmail = event.target.value;
    }

    setInputFields(values);
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/create", {
      data:  [...inputFields]
console.log("Data", data);
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("success!!");
      
    });
    
  };
```

From the above picture you can see that In the browser when i enter the details and submit i can see both the values  that i have entered in console

event.js (Node js)

```
router.post('/create', (req, res) => {

    const data=req.body;
    console.log ("data recieved from client side",data);
    let {ResourcePersonName, ResourcePersonDesignation, ResourcePersonContact, ResourcePersonEmail}= [data];
    db.query(
        `INSERT INTO resourceperson_details (Resourceperson_name,Resourceperson_designation,Resourceperson_contact,Resourceperson_email) VALUES ('${ResourcePersonName}','${ResourcePersonDesignation}','${ResourcePersonContact}','${ResourcePersonEmail}');`,
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);   
            } else {
                console.log(result);
                 res.send("Values Inserted");
             }
         }
     );
});
```

The values i received from the client side can also be seen in my terminal.
[image: server side terminal]

But only one row is being stored at the database and also the data stored in the database says **undefined**.

Can somebody correct me where am i going wrong or suggest what i should be doing here

Comment: In this line `let {ResourcePersonName, ResourcePersonDesignation, ResourcePersonContact, ResourcePersonEmail}= [data];` only one recoed will get inserted to DB

Comment: so should i use a loop ?also if i can see the correct values on the console why does it say undefined in the database. Im a javascript beginner this is quite confusing @ShivamJha

Comment: `data` is already an array, why are you wrapping it between `[` ? Try logging out `ResourcePersonName` after you do  `let {ResourcePersonName, ResourcePersonDesignation, ResourcePersonContact, ResourcePersonEmail}= [data];`

Comment: @ShivamJha tried without the square brackets too, it didnt work. as mentioned its a simple crud application so i havent made the login page